# How to open an excel workbook in vba using string variable

Tags: excel, vba

I have an array of Excel files. I want to assign the file to a string variable and then assign it to Workbooks.Open to open it. I get this error "Application-defined or object-defined error. Any idea where I might be going wrong?

This is my code:

```
Dim x As Workbook
Dim xFileName As String
Dim WkBk As Integer
Dim MyArrayOne as Integer
WkBk = 0

    MyArray1 = Array("filename1", filename2", filename3, filename4")

Do While Count <> MyArrayOne

    xFileName = MyArray1(WkBk)
    Set x = Workbooks.Open(xFileName)
    WkBk = WkBk + 1
Loop
```

Comment: Many items seems not connected. `Count` and `MyArrayOne` for example came from nowhere. You can go and try using UBound and LBound.

Comment: Have you tried debugging to see what line the error is occurring on?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Dim MyArray1 As Variant, i As Long, x As Workbook
MyArray1 = Array("filename_1", "filename_2", ... , "filename_n")

For i = LBound(MyArray1) To UBound(MyArray1)
    Set x = Workbooks.Open(MyArray1(i))
    'do other cool stuffs here
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub M_snb()
    for each it in Array("filename1", "filename2", "filename3", "filename4")
        workbooks.open it
    next
End Sub
```